# Optimizing python function using numpy. where and numpy.unique

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm using a function to determine if resources can be used again or not.
This is the numpy array i'm using.

```
 'Resource_id', 'Start_date', 'end_date', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'overload'
   [548, '2019-05-16', '2019-05-16', '08:45:00', '17:40:00',2],
   [546, '2019-05-16', '2019-05-16', '08:45:00', '17:40:00',2],
   [546, '2019-05-16', '2019-05-16', '08:45:00', '17:40:00',2],
   [543, '2019-05-16', '2019-05-16', '08:45:00', '17:40:00',1],
```

1. First step is to find all resource available on a date, for example (2019-05-16 from 8:30 to 17:30). To achieve this i used np.where like the example below:

   ```
    av_resource_np = resource_availability_np[np.where(
    (resource_availability_np[:,1] <= '2019-05-16')
    & (resource_availability_np[:,2] >= '2019-05-16')
    & (resource_availability_np[:,3] <= '17:30:00') 
    & (resource_availability_np[:,4] >= '08:30:00'))]
   ```
2. Here i try to find unique resource ids and the sum of their overload factor using np.unique()

   ```
    unique_id, count_nb = np.unique(av_resource_np[:,(0,5)], axis=0, return_counts=True)
    availability_mat = np.column_stack((unique_id, count_nb ))
   ```

Which yields the followig results:

```
'Resource_id' 'overload' 'Count'
548           2           1
546           2           2
543           1           1
```

3. A simple filtering is done to select which resource hat can't be used in this date. If a resource is used in the same date `more or equal (>=)` to its`overload`, then we can't use it again.

   ```
     rejected_resources = availability_mat [np.where(availability_mat [:, 2] >= availability_mat [:, 1])]
   ```

**Result** here should be both resource `543` and `546` which can't be used again.

So this is main idea behind my function, the problem here is that it takes more than 60% of the whole program runtime and i would appreciate any advice about how to make it more efficient/faster. Thank you.

Full code:

```
def get_available_rooms_on_date_x(date, start_time, end_time, resource_availability_np):

    av_resource_np = resource_availability_np[np.where(
    (resource_availability_np[:,1] <= date)
    & (resource_availability_np[:,2] >= date)
    & (resource_availability_np[:,3] <= end_time) 
    & (resource_availability_np[:,4] >= start_time))]

    unique_id, count_nb = np.unique(av_resource_np[:,(0,5)], axis=0, return_counts=True)

    availability_mat = np.column_stack((unique_id, count_nb ))
    
    rejected_resources = availability_mat [np.where(availability_mat [:, 2] >= availability_mat [:, 1])]
    
    return rejected_resources
```

Comment: Have you benchmarked this on a larger example? It is quite possible that with larger data sets this will no longer be the bottle neck.

Comment: Yes i did and its slower on bigger datasets.

Comment: Could you show what `resource_availability_np.dtype` is?

Comment: @user7138814 its dtype('O')

Comment: @Mounir, so that means that the values in the array are still regular python objects. You would need to use numpy data types to get more speed, but then you probably need to make a lot of changes to your program. And then maybe it's better to go to a pandas DataFrame or even an sqlite table. Choosing a good data structure is a difficult problem and is much broader scope than this function alone. But to experiment, maybe try with `resource_availability_np.astype('U10')` and see if this function will become faster.

Comment: @user7138814, thank you for your advice, using numpy data types was indeed a good solution giving better results (X2 speed up) but i think that there may be another approach ?